# iOS App Using Google OAuth2(Web App) - "Please close this window."

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, oauth-2.0

I am having the OAuth2 authentication process in my iOS Swift app's UIWebView. I used the official JavaScript OAuth2 library for authentication. However when the authentication completes, it goes to a webpage only with text saying "Please close this window.". I believe it is trying to do window.close() or something like that.

Is there anyway my app could react to this "Please close this window."?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to resolve it?